# Echo/Print Query Result at Controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to display my Model query return result in my controller, but I don't know how to do it. could you please show me? Thanks in advance

**Controller:**

```
function updateJobsheetCDC()
    {
        $prnID = $this->input->post('prnID');

        $this->load->model('Ipss_model');
        $data['prnEmail'] = $this->Ipss_model->prnEmailList($prnID);

        echo $data['prnEmail']['name'];
    }
```

**Model:**

```
function prnEmailList($prnID)
    {
        $q = $this->db->query("SELECT pm.* , prm.*,e.* from  principal_master pm ,principal prm,email e where pm.prnID=e.prnID and prm.prID= pm.prID and e.prnID='" .$prnID."'");

        if($q->num_rows()>0) {
          foreach($q ->result() as $row) 
          {
             $data[] = $row;    
          }
          return $data;
        }       
    }
```

I have tried 
         ***echo $data['prnEmail']['name'];*** but it do not work. It shows Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: name.

Comment: Just try with `print_r($data)` in controller.

Comment: make sure do you have records in table!

Comment: `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($data); echo"</pre>"; exit;`  use this for better output

Comment: @HiteshSolanki it is print full array but I could not print single column by echo $data['prnEmail']['name'];

Comment: what you get in output?

Comment: Full array value. Array returns  Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [eid] => 4 [prnID] => 2 [name] => Zainal [designation] => SC [email] => zabedin@zp-bd.com ) )

Comment: @MasudSarker To access your data individually; you can follow this pattern: $data[0]->variableName. For example: echo $data[0]->eid; and so on for rest of the variables

Comment: @Bimal It show Message: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: If you have not changed the code then you can access value by: echo $data['prnEmail'][0]->name;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multi-dimentinal array returning from model. So you have to loop over them then print data

```
function updateJobsheetCDC()
{
    $prnID = $this->input->post('prnID');

    $this->load->model('Ipss_model');
    $data = $this->Ipss_model->prnEmailList($prnID);
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
      echo $value->name; 
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows this error. Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array